# Footer menu list to open up not down, jsfiddle included

Tags: css, list

I have a menu I'm using in the footer, and I would like to get the list items to open "up", not down.

Live sample: http://jsfiddle.net/tVCUr/1/

If someone could help me out with this I would really appreciate it.

P.S.- The height of the li items will vary, so I would like to avoid having to specify a height in pixels if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add `bottom: 100%` to `.dropmenu ul`:

```css
.dropmenu ul{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    display: none;
    width: 140px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Here it is in your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tVCUr/2/

Comment: Oh man I knew I was missing something small and obvious! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/tVCUr/4/

Just add to .dropmenu ul change the drop down:

```
bottom:100%;
```